# Django: Different LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL Workflow for Admin than the normal User

Tags: django

In my Django App settings I've mentioned the following 2 lines in settings.py, it works fine for the normal user but is not good enough for the Admin.

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/my_app/profile/'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = '/my_app/login'
```

When I log out from the Admin, it takes me to the login page of the user, as mentioned in the above LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL. What I want is that admin logout redirect should go to the Admin login page, not the user login page.

snippet from `urls.py`

```
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
```

Can anyone suggest the best way to deal with this issue?

**EDIT:**
I tried to extend Django's Admin `base.html` which contains the Logout part.

```
{% block userlinks %}
    {% if site_url %}
        <a href="{{ site_url }}">{% trans 'View site' %}</a> /
    {% endif %}
    {% if user.is_active and user.is_staff %}
        {% url 'django-admindocs-docroot' as docsroot %}
        {% if docsroot %}
            <a href="{{ docsroot }}">{% trans 'Documentation' %}</a> /
        {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
    {% if user.has_usable_password %}
        <a href="{% url 'admin:password_change' %}">{% trans 'Change password' %}</a> /
    {% endif %}
    <a href="{% url 'admin:logout' %}">{% trans 'Log out' %}</a>
{% endblock %}
```

How can I change this `admin:logout` functionality so that it redirects to admin login page?